# Android Progress Dialog shown up so late?

Tags: android, progressdialog

Here is the problem

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ContactMainActivity.this, "", 
            "Loading. Please wait...",true);
     setContentView(R.layout.contactlist);
        contactListView=getListView();
        contactListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        contactListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


Thread t =  new Thread() {

        public void run() {

        try{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {



            //stuff that updates ui
                     queryAllRawContacts();
                     progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            registerForContextMenu(contactListView);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

        }

        // dismiss the progress dialog



        }

        };
        t.start();



}
```

this is onCreate method of my activity class.

This activity actually one tab of a tabwidget. So when I click this tab and run the activity, it waits about 2 seconds and then show progress dialog like 10 millisec and updates the UI with the data. and dismiss progress dialog. What I would like to achieve is that as soon as the tab is clicked, the progress dialog will be shown and it takes about 2-3 seconds to load data. after loading and updating the UI the progress bar will be dismissed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryAllRawContacts()` needs to not be run on the UI thread. Change your code to the following:

```
Thread t =  new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    queryAllRawContacts();
    try{
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //stuff that updates ui     
          progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
      });
      registerForContextMenu(contactListView);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

    }

    // dismiss the progress dialog

    }

  };
t.start();
```

Comment: I changed it as you say. Now when I run it it shows immediately. However when it comes to dismiss it kills the app. It doesnt update the UI?

Comment: You must have some other problem with your app. What does you logcat say?

Comment: Thank you I got it worked basically I moved  contactListView.setAdapter(adapter); in to runOnUithread method which basically updates Ui. now works like a charm:) thank you.